# animated image is over-layed or overimposed on top of the navigation bar

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a hero image to which I have applied an entrance animation that is 3s delayed.

It works OK as you see below

[the image in its normal state after entrance animation is activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsTm5.jpg)

But once the user starts scrolling,  the hero image becomes over-imposed or over-layed on top of the navigation menu, as demonstrated in the screenshot below

[the image is over-relayed or over-imposed on the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trl3S.png)

I have taken a screenshot of the css rules being applied to the hero image, check it out:

[a screenshot showing the css rules applied to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POSg6.png)

Comment: Share your code, help us to help you

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?